# SQL Server - show distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, distinct

| Policy ID | YTD Value | Business Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 120 | Taxes |
| 1 | 100 | Taxes |
| 1 | 330 | Taxes |
| 2 | 120 | Taxes |
| 2 | 130 | Taxes |

I have the table above. What I would like to change it to is

| Policy ID | YTD Value | Business Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 550 | Taxes |
| 2 | 250 | Taxes |

Basically, add up the totals using sum, but combining the `PolicyID` columns to where they are the same. I've tried using distinct after policy ID and group by and since the other values are different, it still shows each entry separate.

How would I do this?

Comment: Could you edit your question and share your data as text not images ? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4286884

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: You need to UNPIVOT for the Taxes # columns and sum them. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I looked at the link you sent here @Alex, but I don't understand it. Can you provide an example to clear it up? Would I need a unpivot each entry (there are more than displayed here) that I don't want to group by?

Comment: Is this not just a simple `GROUP BY PolicyID, BusinessType` and `SUM(YTDValue)`?

Comment: When I try to group by, it still shows all the records. 

    Select * from data group by policyID, businesstype, sum(YTDValue) still shows up as listing every policy ID multiple times.

Comment: That's not even valid TSQL for multiple reasons, not sure what you meant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple aggregation can do the trick :

```
SELECT Policy_ID, SUM(YTD_Value) AS YTD_Value, Business_Type
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Policy_ID, Business_Type
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/B0WexW9U)